# How to check if a lazy loading propery returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My MVC view has the following code -

```
@foreach (var d in Model.ItineraryDays)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => d.DayPlus1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(d.Listing.Name, "Details", "Port", new { Id = d.ListingId }, null)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (d.Listing.Port.Country != null)
                    {
                        @Html.ActionLink(d.Listing.Port.Country.Name, "Details", "Country", new { Id = d.Listing.Port.Country.Id }, null)
                    }              
            </td>
```

When (d.Listing.Port.Country != null) encounters a null value it returns an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' exception.

Both Port and Country are lazy loading properties. If 'Country' != mull, then 'Port' must have an entry. (Not all Listings have an entry  in Port, hence the null check).

Something wrong with my approach, not sure what!

regards, Guy

Addendum: Repository code:

```
    public Itinerary GetItineraryFromId(int Id)
    {
        var itinerary = context.Itineraries
                .Include(i => i.ItineraryDays)
                .Include(i => i.ItineraryStartDates)
                .Where(i => i.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();

        return(itinerary);
    }
```

- ItineraryDay has nav. property>> public virtual Listing Listing { get; set;}
- Listing has nav. property>> public virtual Port Port { get; set; }
- Port has nav. propert>> public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Since both Port and Country are lazy loaded you would need to start your conditional check at the Port level

```
 @if (d.Listing.Port != null) {
      if (d.Listing.Port.Country != null) {
           ... Do Something
      }
 } else {
      ... Handle null scenario
 }
```

Comment: The following: @if (d.Listing.Port != null)
                    {
                        if (d.Listing.Port.Country != null)
                        {@Html.ActionLink(d.Listing.Port.Country.Name, "Details", "Country", new { Id = d.Listing.Port.Country.Id }, null)}
                    } gives the same error.

Comment: Could it be possible that the Listing property is also being lazy loaded?  You should be able to set a breakpoint in your view and check to see which exact property is null when it gets to that line.

Comment: Listing isn't lazy loaded. What I should add is that if Port !=null then Country will 100% have an entry. Which should mean no check is necessary for Country. (Listing is a list of all possible 'brochure' entries for a cruise-line catalogue eg Miami, KeyWest, Nassau, At Sea, Crossing Dateline. Where this code breaks is when it enumerates through a Listing collection and encounters an entry such as 'At Sea' which of course has a null entry for the PortId property used to navigate to that entity..

Comment: Can you please post your view code as well as specify exactly where in the code the exception is occurring