# How to check if a lazy loading propery returns null (reformulated)

Tags: linq, entity-framework

This was originally posted here:
[How to check if a lazy loading propery returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387116/how-to-check-if-a-lazy-loading-propery-returns-null/25387185?noredirect=1#comment39628310_25387185)
..but wasn't answered, possibly due to the question and supporting code not being clear enough. (I'd like to delete it but am not sure if this will have consequences on my ability to post)

I think the question has value, so I have reformulated it for clarity:

The following code:

```
var itinerary = context.Itineraries
.Include(i => i.ItineraryDays.Select(id => id.Listing.Port.Country))
.Include(i => i.ItineraryStartDates)
.Where(i => i.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

passes data to a view, which throws an exception 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object', at the following code**:

```
@foreach (var d in Model.ItineraryDays)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => d.DayPlus1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(d.Listing.Name, "Details", "Port", new { Id = d.ListingId }, null)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (d.Listing != null) **
                    {
                       //
                    }
```

Some points:

- d.Listing always has a value, and is never null
- d.Listing.Port can return a null
- the exception only occurs when d.Listing.Port is null

Can anyone tell me why the exception is thrown?

**UPDATE**
Just discovered that my code does, under certain circumstances, handle the nulls without throwing an exception,  but not in every case. e.g. 1) Good 2) Exception

```
1) @Html.DisplayFor(model => d.Listing.Port.Country.Name)
2) @Html.ActionLink(d.Listing.Port.Country.Name, "Details", "Country", new { Id = d.Listing.Port.Country.Id }, null)
```

regards, Guy

Comment: It's probably `d` that is null. Show more code so we can see what's `d`.

Comment: you should not create a duplicate question, what you should do is improve the question and it will go to the front page, please read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: @Yuliam. I wasn't sure how to go about this because of the comments left for the original post. The reformulated post is markedly different which means that these posts would not tie up with the changes, and create confusion. In the future I'll try to improve and repost in a way that minimizes this 'disconnect'.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you precedent post, for me one possible solution is:

```
.Include(i => i.ItineraryDays.Select(id => id.Listing.Port.Country))
```

this should be evaluated after the hit to the database, and, as Post is null, Port.Country throws.

to validate this idea:

- check the emitted sql, and/or
- `.Include(i => i.ItineraryDays.Select(id => id.Listing.Port != null ?id.Listing.Port.Country : null))`

Comment: ...using your code I get > The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties....

Comment: @haim770. d is definitely not null. (I set a break point where the exception occurs to check this).